# Spring Data crud repository query always returns 0

Tags: spring-boot, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin, crud-repository

I have a service and repository class with entity class

```
package com.example.onlinebookstore.service;

import com.example.onlinebookstore.repository.CustomerRepository;
import com.example.onlinebookstore.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CustomerService implements ICustomerService {
    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    public String login(Customer customer) {
        List<Customer> cus = customerRepository.findByUsername(customer.getUserName());
        
        if (cus != null || cus.size() > 0) {
            if (cus.get(0).getUserName().equals(customer.getPassword())){
                return "Success";
            }
        }
        return "Failed";
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.onlinebookstore.repository;

import com.example.onlinebookstore.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {

    List<Customer> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

```
package com.example.onlinebookstore.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonProperty(value="Id")
    @Column(name = "id")
    int id;

    @JsonProperty(value="Username")
    @Column(name = "username")
    String username;

    @JsonProperty(value="Password")
    @Column(name = "password")
    String password;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUserName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

[This is DB data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of6AT.png)

[This is postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP0iS.png)

I want to filter DB data according to username but it always returns 0 (zero). This is working when add findAll() method. Why it is always 0?

I want to filter data according to username. CustomerService.java line 18 returns 0. DB is postgressql. DB column is customer (id, username, password).

Comment: Look at your database image again. `Malshani` is in the password column.

Comment: problem lies with db data. from the db it should be `1234`. so your post data request should be
{"username": "1234", "password": "Malshani"}

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but `if (cus != null || cus.size() > 0)` should actually be `if (cus != null && cus.size() > 0)`. Or just `if (cus.size() > 0)` because Spring JPA will return an empty list if there are no results.